# Fittext will only work when window is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am using the fittext JS plugin to resize my headings on a page I am working on. For some reason it only kicks in if/once you adjust your window size, I cant seem to figure out why it is doing this.

Anyone have any ideas? Here is a link:
http://voltagenewmedia.ca/testserver/dry/#/homepage

Thanks!

Comment: i'm having the same problem. Did you handle the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is down so I can't actually see what the problem is.  Fittext should resize immediately and then update on resize:

```
  // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
  var resizer = function () {
    $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
  };

  // Call once to set.
  resizer();

  // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
  $(window).on('resize', resizer);
```

Are you waiting until the DOM is loaded before you use the plug-in?

Comment: Sorry server seems to be having an issue it should be up soon. Can you explain how I should be loading the DOM? Not sure exactly what you mean. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Sites back up now if that helps :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it seems to be working, but im having problems setting the font sizes, I want the font slightly bigger then its displaying now, but still im not 100% its working properly.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still having the issue, this fix works for me

Replace this code inside `jquery.fittext.js`

```
// Call once to set.
resizer();
```

With this code,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    resizer();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem that was driving me nuts. The element holding my text could not shrink within it's container because the max font size was too large, so I start it off with the width of the parent container. Then I just use the fittext algorithm once after initializing to get it loading properly and it seems to solve the issue.

```
$("#hero").find('h1').fitText(.65, { maxFontSize: '142px' });

$("#hero").find('h1').each(function(){
    startSize = Math.max(Math.min($('#hero').width() / (compressor.*10)));
    $(this).css({'font-size':startSize});
});
```